# should i use non cluster index

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I am working on performance tuning of Linq to SQL statement.

I tried transaction scope with read uncommitted. intesion was to use NOLOCK alternate. Didn't give me good result

Query i am tuning has 7 tables with count as below

```
select count(1) from [Extent1] --3211160
select count(1) from [Extent2] -- 2357380
select count(1) from [Extent3] -- 14118987
select count(1) from [Extent4] -- 14118639
select count(1) from [Extent5] -- 30196545
select count(1) from [Extent6] -- 14118883
select count(1) from [Extent7] --53066591
```

Extent1.CreatedOn sorting is consuming 97% of Execution plan.

Does using non cluster index on CreatedOn column help any improvement?

[image]

Any suggestion with better approach to solve this kind of issue also appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is the version of EF ?

Comment: we are using EF 5